# Delphi TTrayIcon BalloonFlags Customize icon

Tags: delphi, winapi

I want to change the icon in the balloon.

```
TrayIcon1.BalloonFlags := bfWarning;
```

This type can be selected only four kinds of icons.
I would like to put your own icons.
Help me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This control is a wrapper around the Win32 API [`Shell_NotifyIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159.aspx). As such it reflects to you the capabilities offered by the platform, mostly.

The available icons are described in the documentation for the associated struct, [`NOTIFYICONDATA`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773352.aspx). The options are:

> - NIIF_NONE: No icon.
> - NIIF_INFO: An information icon.
> - NIIF_WARNING: A warning icon.
> - NIIF_ERROR: An error icon.
> - NIIF_USER: Windows XP SP2 and later. Windows XP: Use the icon identified in hIcon as the notification balloon's title icon. Windows
>     Vista and later: Use the icon identified in hBalloonIcon as the
>     notification balloon's title icon.

This means that the underlying API supports user icons. But the Delphi wrapper does not offer you access to that functionality.

The solution is to call `Shell_NotifyIcon` directly, specifying `NIIF_USER` and passing the icon in `hBalloonIcon`. Or in `hIcon` if your code is executing on XP.